# How to get at the underlying object inside a Rails form or field_for block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't figure-out how to get at the underlying object in a form_for or field_for block.

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
<% f.fields_for :children do |child_form| %>
  <%= render :partial => "#{child_form.underlying_object.class.name.downcase}" %>
<% end %>
```

and :children is a polymorphic has_many association.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Isn't it just

```
<% f.fields_for :children do |child_form| %>
<%= render :partial => "#{child_form.object.class.name.downcase}" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Oh so close! :-)

child_form.object.class.name is the magic.

Thanks!