# Rails 4: show uploaded image when editing form - getting undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, simple-form, cocoon-gem

How do I show the uploaded image (associated) when editing the form? I tried to display like so:

**_item_fields.haml**

```
.nested-fields

  = image_tag f.img.url if f.img.url?
  = f.input :item

  = f.file_field :img

  = link_to_remove_association "remove item", f
```

Where it should display if there's a `.url` but I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method 'img' #<SimpleForm::FormBuilder:0x007ff0eff8aee8>
```

**_form.haml**

```
= simple_form_for @model, html: {multipart: true} do |f|
  = f.simple_fields_for :items do |m|

    = render 'item_fields', f: m

    = link_to_add_association 'add item', f, :items
    = f.button :submit
```

In my **show.haml**, I have this

```
- @model.items.each do |m|
  - if m.img
    = image_tag m.img.url
  - else
    no image
```

this shows the image correctly.

Comment: If you inspect `f` in _iten_fields.haml, what do you get?

Comment: What is the attribute name that you got in item model to store the images?

Comment: @paven, I updated my post, the show page shows the image correctly. But it just doesn't show the image when inside the edit form, I store it in img. Is that what you're asking? Sorry if not, I'm trying to brush up on my rails.

Comment: @KenStipek what do you mean? How do I inspect this?

Comment: Is there something more about the error? Something like `undefined local variable or method img for class`?

Comment: @paven This is the error: `undefined local variable or method 'img' for #<#<Class:0x007ff0eb9b8a28>:0x007ff0f39dd488>` and its highlighting to the this: `= image_tag f.img.url`

Comment: `- puts f.inspect` at the top of _item_fields.haml should display the result in your console.

Comment: @paven Actually, if I take the `if f.img.url?` off, I get the for class error, but if I put it on, I get `undefined method 'img' for #<SimpleForm::FormBuilder:0x007ff0f11527c0>` for SimpleForm FormBuilder error.

Comment: @KenStipek Doing that gives me a bunch of text: `#<SimpleForm::FormBuilder:0x007ff0eff47e90 @nested_child_index={}, and so on...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find this works: Inside the form use `f.object` to get the underlying object to build the correct url for the `image_tag`

```
image_tag f.object.img.url
```

I'd post a reference, but it's not well documented. There's a bit of a  discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556359/how-to-get-at-the-underlying-object-inside-a-rails-form-or-field-for-block).